# Resize font-size based on determinated px and box width with js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to resize the font-size (like vw) of my tag p with a based size of 16px, in proportion on her box resize.
16px in vw is equal to 1.119vw, but this is the 100% of width; in my case I need the 50% of vw.

```
<div class="box"> 
 <p> Resize my text </p>
</div>
```

```
.box {
 width: 50%;
}

p {
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you don't provide clear expectations.
you can do something like:

```css
font-size: calc(1.119vw / 2);
```

to calculate a font-size in pixel depending on `vw` then divide by 2 to achieve this.